# Proxy authentification with Selenium ChromeDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to set up a proxy which require authentication. I have used proxy object and `option.setProxy()` but i'm am still prompted with authentication window.

When I specify in the proxy url (`username:pwg@ip:port`) then the proxy is not taken into account at all (checked with Wireshark).

This is my code :

```
    int randomProxy = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, proxies.length);

    String PROXY = String.format("******:******@%s:*****",proxies[randomProxy]);


    System.out.println(PROXY);
    org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
     .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
     .setSslProxy(PROXY);
    proxy.setSocksUsername("******");
    proxy.setSocksPassword("******");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/var/chromedriver/chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setProxy(proxy);

    int randomAgent = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, userAgents.length);
    options.addArguments(userAgents[randomAgent]);

    this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set my proxy:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort);
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to set up authentification credentials somewhere (user name + password)